# JPA EJB установка DataSource

Tags: java-ee, jpa, ejb

Я создал DataSource на сервере  GlassFish, как мне дать понять JPA что бы он работал через этот  DataSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В тег `jta-data-source` файла persistence.xml прописать JNDI-имя источника данных.